# Fill a JSON from another using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

Given an empty JSON 1:

```
JSON1 = {
  "person": { "firstName": "" },
  "products": { "packName": "", "packSize": "" }
}
```

and JSON 2 which has more fields than JSON 1:

```
JSON2 = {
  "person": { "firstName": "Ahmed", "job": "Doctor" },
  "products": { "packName": "antibiotic", "packSize": "large" }
}
```

I want to fill JSON 1 with its corresponding values in JSON 2

```
{
  "person": { "firstName": "Ahmed" },
  "products": { "packName": "antibiotic", "packSize": "large" }
}
```

I have tried several methods but not getting there

```
var newObj = {};
var parsedJson1 = JSON.parse(tw.local.JSON1);
var parsedJson2 = JSON.parse(tw.local.JSON2);
var i;

for (i in parsedJson1) {
    var key=i;
    var subkey=i;
    for (j in parsedJson2) {
        var k=j;
        var s=j;
        if (key == k && subkey == s) {
            newObj[key][subkey] = parsedJson2[j];
        }
    }
}
tw.local.stringifiedJSON = JSON.stringify(newObj);
```

Comment: what are the value of variable k, s, key and subkey, you didn't initialize them how is the if condition working ?

Comment: key = i and k= j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how to do it:

Note that this assumes the following:

1. you know the second object will have all required keys.
2. all values at the first level are objects
3. note that this solution will work only for the specified structure, and if you need to handle any variations you will need to make it more defensive.

Steps:

- iterate over the valid keys (all keys on `JSON1`)
- for each valid key, add it to `newObj` and iterate over valid `subKeys`
- copy values from `JSON2` to `newObj`

*Note: I changed your code a bit so it can be executed on this site*

```js
const JSON1 = `{
  "person": { "firstName": "" },
  "products": { "packName": "", "packSize": "" }
}`;

const JSON2 = `{
  "person": { "firstName": "Ahmed", "job": "Doctor" },
  "products": { "packName": "antibiotic", "packSize": "large" }
}`;


const parsedJson1 = JSON.parse(JSON1);
const parsedJson2 = JSON.parse(JSON2);
const newObj = {};
const validKeys = Object.keys(parsedJson1);

for (let i of Object.keys(parsedJson1)) {
  if (newObj[i] === undefined) {
    newObj[i] = {};
  }
  for (let j of Object.keys(parsedJson1[i])) {
    newObj[i][j] = parsedJson2[i][j];
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursion to traverse target object for robustness. I formatted code for better readability.

```
function getNode(obj, path) {
    var ret = obj;
    try {
        // replace forEach with for-loop for browser compatibilities
        path.forEach(function (p) {
            ret = ret[p];
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return ret;
}

function fillJSONWithAnother(target, source, path) {
    if (!(target && source)) return target;
    // Assign path as an empty array for first call
    path = path || [];

    // Get target node and source node for comparing
    var targetValue = getNode(target, path);
    var sourceValue = getNode(source, path);
    // targetValue is not a leaf node (i.e. is Object), should traverse its children nodes
    if (targetValue && typeof targetValue === "object") {
        for (var key in targetValue) {
            fillJSONWithAnother(target, source, path.concat([key]));
        }
    }
    // targetValue is a leaf node (i.e. not Object) and source value exists, set corresponding value
    else if (sourceValue !== undefined) {
        var node = getNode(target, path.slice(0, path.length - 1));
        node[path[path.length - 1]] = sourceValue;
    }
    return target;
}

// Test case
var obj1 = {
    "person": {
        "firstName": ""
    },
    "products": {
        "packName": "",
        "packSize": "l"
    }
};
var obj2 = {
    "person": {
        "firstName": "Ahmed",
        "job": "Doctor"
    },
    "products": {
        "packName": "antibiotic",
        "packSize": "large"
    }
}
fillJSONWithAnother(obj1, obj2);
// {"person":{"firstName":"Ahmed"},"products":{"packName":"antibiotic","packSize":"large"}}
```